# Related to -useproxyclass converter option

Tags: javacard

What does -useproxyclass option does for JCDK 3.0.1 and above? Can you please share some links, materials related to this.

The reason I am asking this is if my applet has any references to global platform libraries the converter is failing with the error:

**error: Could not find a java compiler (javac). Do you have a Java JRE (not SDK) installed?
com.sun.javacard.converter.ConverterException**

But If I am passing this **-useproxyclass** option to the converter, the error is not shown.